# Incorrect Name Value For Admin Store

Tags: magento-1.9, product, multistore, name

Please take a look at screen shot of table **catalog_product_entity_varchar** below.
[image]

The **attribute_id** '71' is the ID for attribute **name**. I have 2 stores.
For both stores the product have same **name** value i.e. 'SURGICAL STEEL DOUBLE JEWELED NAVEL BANANA'. Please see screen shots below.

**Default Store**
[image]

**Store 1**(this is the default store)
[image]

**Store 2**
[image]

Is this some kind of bug or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

I checked it is happening for other products also and this a **grouped** products for incorrect values are saved.

'BNDJ' is the **SKU** of the grouped product.

Comment: How did you upload your products to magento? using csv import?

Comment: I used MAGMI to import products

Comment: Recheck the mapping you used in your import profile